# Show there exists a subsequence such that $\frac{n_j}{\phi(n_j)}\geq0.99\log\log(n_j)$

Tags: number-theory

> Show there exists a subsequence $n_j$ of natural numbers for which $\frac{n_j}{\phi(n_j)}\geq0.99\log\log(n_j)$.
>
> Given hint: $\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{\log y}\sum_{m\leq y}\frac{1}{m}=1$

My work. If $n\in \mathbb N$ is divisible by all primes $p\leq y$
I have shown that $\frac{n}{\phi(n)}\geq \sum_{m\leq y}\frac{1}{m}$ and have also shown that the product of all primes $p\leq y$ is less than $y^y$.

As a subsequence I let $n_j$ be the product of the first $j$ prime numbers, which means that $p_1\cdots p_j=n_j\leq y^y$ taking $y=p_j$ and so we have $\frac{\log n_j}{\log y}\leq y$

Is this the right start and how can I incorporate the hint?

Comment: asked some hours ago at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3545120/show-there-exists-a-subsequence-such-that-fracn-j-phin-j-geq0-99-log-log  and deleted a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track. If $n_j$ is the product of the first $j$ prime numbers, i.e. $n_j=p_1\cdots p_j$ then
$$\frac{n_j}{\phi(n_j)}\geq \sum_{m\leq p_j}\frac{1}{m}.$$
Since $\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{\log y}\sum_{m\leq y}\frac{1}{m}=1$ for $j$ sufficiently large
$$\frac{n_j}{\phi(n_j)}\geq 0.999\log(p_j)$$
We note that $\log(j\log(p_j))\geq \log(\log(n_j))$, so it suffices to show that eventually
$$0.999\log(p_j)\geq 0.99\log(j\log(p_j))$$
that is
$$\frac{\log(p_j)}{\log(j\log(p_j))}\geq \frac{0.99}{0.999}\in (0,1).$$
So it remains to show that
$$\lim_{j\to +\infty}\frac{\log(p_j)}{\log(j\log(p_j))}=1$$
which holds because $p_j \sim j\log(j)$  by the Prime Number Theorem.

Comment: Then $n_j\leq p_j^{p_j}$ and $\log(\log(n_j))\leq \log(p_j)+\log(\log(p_j))$. You may use this inequality and find the same result without PNT.